# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 67 more

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm testing my endpoints in offline mode mocking/faking all the data. Based on the [Firebase Unit testing of Cloud functions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#testing_http_functions), they use it as following:

```
const req = { query: {text: 'input'} };
const res = {
  redirect: (code, url) => {
    assert.equal(code, 303);
    assert.equal(url, 'new_ref');
    done();
  }
};

// Invoke addMessage with our fake request and response objects
myFunctions.addMessage(req, res);
```

My code is similar:

```
const req = {

}

const res = {

}

updateUser(req, res)

// and this is 'updateUser()' function in another file
export default functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => { ... }
```

So I'm getting the following error:

**Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 67 more.**

How can I avoid putting all the 67 properties? I just want to provide 'method', 'query' or 'body' properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @mamichels, with their help I've managed to work it out. So I'm posting the solution just in case, it may help someone. I'm using Firebase CF with Express.

```
import * as express from "express"

...

it("should do something", async () => {
    const req = {
      method: "POST"
    }

    const res = {

    }

    updateUser(req as express.Request, res as express.Response)
})
```

And my updateUser looks like:

```
export default functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

Comment: Hi, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just type it as:
`(req as Request), res => ...`